# How to Generate Normal Random Samples within Mean±3Sigma

Tags: r, random, normal-distribution

I want to draw normal random numbers in an array of order ((100*8)*5000) with a specific Mean (M) and Standard Deviation (S) but I want them to be only within the range M±3S, so that I don't have any outliers in my array exceeding those limits.

Any Suggestion? I want to write a program in R based on this array for some simulation studies. I am using following R Code to generate my Data Set:

```
for(i in 1:5000){
for(j in 1:8){
            Dat[,j,i]=rnorm(100,mean=muu[j],sd=sigma[j])
         }
         }
```

Now, We want to  get rid of those values which are higher than muu±3sigma in the above data. Definitely, We have to replace discarded values with fresh values so that the dimension of the Dat array keep intact.

Comment: Just write down the inverse cdf of your distribution. With that, you can map from uniform (0,1) draws.

Answer (score 2):

## First Solution

Here is a start but I bet there is a more elegant solution.
First generate a sample next step is to subset it to your desired values. Of course you have to adjust values to your desire.

```
set.seed(123)
rs <- rnorm(10000, mean = 10, sd = 3)
rs1 <- rs[ rs >= -19 & rs <= 19  ]
```

## Second (better) solution

I think my first solutions didn't work so well. I have just written some code that might be perfect for your purposes. Here are the steps.

- create an array of NAs with the required dimensions
- fill it with random numbers
- create a logical vector where `TRUE`s are for the desired conditions
- subset the `data` based on that vector and replace the values where TRUE is TRUE (pardon my words game) with the mean used to generate samples

  data <- array(NA, dim = c(100, 8, 5000))

  ```
  for(i in 1:5000){
      data[ , , i] <- rnorm(800, 3, 1)
  }

  bound <- 3 + c(-1, 1)*3*1
  pr <- data <= bound[1] | data >= bound[2]
  data[pr] <- 3
  ```

Comment: This is *almost* right I think. I think what you really want is to parameterize your mean and sd, and then filter to mean plus or minus 3*sd.

Comment: This solution is perfect, if we have just one replication but for my case, I am using two for loops (given below) to generate a data set:

`for(i in 1:5000){
for(j in 1:8){
   Dat[,j,i]=rnorm(100,mean=muu[j],sd=sigma[j])
   }
   }`

For this case, how can I get my desired data sets?

Comment: I am sorry @KashifAli but I do not think I get what you are supposed to do. First, you want a 3 dimensions array, say 100 row * 8 columns * 5000 levels? If so, but even if it is not so, you want a simple simulation or a finite number of simulations? and these simulations, arraigned by rows or by columns?

Comment: I am sorry @KashifAli but I still do not get it. Your code seems to say that you want to generate 8 sample each one with mean from 1 to 8, and for each set of of random samples (with mean from 1 to 8) you want 5000 array levels. So, let me recap: an array with 8 columns, 100 rows and 5000 layers. Each column is the result of a `rnorm` where column 1 has mean 1 and sd 1, column 2 has mean 2 and sd 2 and so on.

Comment: Actually I forget to mention means are same which are denoted by muu[j] and so does standard deviations.

Comment: Take means to be 3 for all 8 columns and Standard Deviations to be 1.